# Magento import overwrites products

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, import, csv

I'm importing my products in an empty magento store from an .csv and it worked fine while testing with 1 product, but now that I want to import all of them I get the problem the previous product gets overwritten by the next one so after the import I only have one product in my store.

```
include_once "../app/Mage.php";
include_once "../downloader/Maged/Controller.php";

Mage::init();

// Set the store id
$app = Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$Simpleproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

if(($handle = fopen("simple.csv", "r")) !== FALSE){
fgetcsv($handle);
while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE){
  try{
    $Simpleproduct
      ->setWebsiteIds(array(1))
      ->setAttributeSetId(4)
      ->setTypeId('simple')
      ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'))
      ->setName($data[4])
      ->setWeight(4.0000)
      ->setStatus(1) //(1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
      ->setTaxClassId(2) //(0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
      ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE)
      ->setPrice($data[3]);

     if($Simpleproduct->save()){
        echo "product ".$sku." Was created<br>";
        $row++;
     }
  }catch(Exception $e){
    die();
    echo "<p><b>";
    echo $e;
    echo "</p></b><br>";
    echo $data[4];
  }
  }
}else{
    echo "Handle == false";
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem.

```
$Simpleproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
```

is outside the `while` loop so you use the same product instance everytime.
The first product gets inserger. When calling `save()` the product instances gets an id and any other operation you do with the product instance will affect the product with that id.
Move the line above inside the `while` loop and it should work.

```
while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE){
  try{
     $Simpleproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
      ....
  } catch .... {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep **$Simpleproduct** outside loop, just add this line in the end of **try** block

```
$Simpleproduct->unsetData();
```